# How do i get the Email Address of a PR owner from within Github actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a custom action I am working on which requires a "user-email".  I want to pass in the PR OWNER's email into it.   I thought it was as simple as saying:

```
with:
  user-email: "${{ github.event.pull_request.owner.email }}"
```

but it seems to keep passing in empty string.

I was looking at the content of the context for the pull_request object, located at: https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request

I was thinking that I could also try:

```
with:
  user-email: "${{ github.event.pull_request.pull_request.user.email }}"
```

And that seemed to be passing in an empty string as well. What am I missing?

Comment: The email address of a GitHub profile is only accessible via API when the owner has made it public in their profile settings, which very often isn't the case.

Comment: While that might make sense for the public github, Our company is using the github enterprise version, which i figured would expose all of our emails to each other.

Comment: Ah, in this case, there are some options! I'll add an answer.

Comment: So it seems like the entity did now expose the emails to github actions, so to bypass it I would just look at the most recent github log to denote who to email.  Weird that it wouldnt show up in an action but you could just query logs instead.

Comment: The commit email address might not be associated with a GitHub login, though, or somebody might have configured their GitHub account to [anonymize their email address](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github).

Comment: The internal github associates their business email to their github email.  In the off-chance that it doesnt, say a malformed config, it would return the user in a non-email format, for a different pipeline.  One thing which was interesting is that the user object doesnt expose the email.  Which was a bummer, but an action does have git history, so i leveraged that to find corresponding emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your organization has a verified domain, you can query matching email addresses as part of the [`User` object](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#user) (the `organizationVerifiedDomainEmails` field).

For example, using the GitHub CLI, for the provided user and org, the query would look like

```bash
query='
  query ($login: String!, $org: String!) {
    user(login: $login) {
      organizationVerifiedDomainEmails(login: $org)
    }
  }
'
gh api graphql -f login=USERNAME -f org=ORGANIZATION -f query="$query"
```

with a response that looks like

```json
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "organizationVerifiedDomainEmails": [
        "someuser@someorg.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To extract the first one of these (if there are multiple):

```bash
email=$(gh api graphql -f login=USERNAME -f org=ORGANIZATION -f query="$query" \
    --jq '.data.user.organizationVerifiedDomainEmails[0]')
```

To use that in an action triggered by a PR, you could have a `run` step that fetches it, and then sets the email address as an output:

```yaml
- name: Get email address
  id: get-email
  env:
    login: ${{ github.event.pull_request.owner.login }}
  run: |
    email=$(gh api graphql -f login="$login" -f org=ORGANIZATION -f query='
      query ($login: String!, $org: String!) {
        user(login: $login) {
          organizationVerifiedDomainEmails(login: $org)
        }
      }
    ' --jq '.data.user.organizationVerifiedDomainEmails[0]')

    echo "email=$email" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

- name: Do something with the email
  with:
    user-email: ${{ steps.get-email.outputs.email }}
  uses: # etc.
```

You might be able to also parametrize the `ORGANIZATION` from the pull request, or just hardcode it.

Even though the non-Enterprise docs have this field, it looks like it's only populated for organizations on an Enterprise plan.